# Meaning warning "File is touched by more than one package"

Tags: linux, driver, buildroot

I am creating a simple linux kernel with buildroot and I am adding a small driver I've done myself, I created the `Config.in` file and `drivername.mk` to be able to select the driver in `make menuconfig` succesfully.

When executing `make` to build the image, the compilation goes correctly until my driver starts to compile, it looks to compile and create the image right but I get loooots of warnings saying that different files in `./lib/gcc/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf/` are touched by more than one package: `[u'host-gcc-initial', u'host-gcc-final']`.

Anyone can explain me a bit about this issue and what is causing it? Do you need any more info to know what is happening? Is it safe to ignore them?

Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, doing a search on 'touched by more than one package', I found http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2017-October/205602.html, where we find that this warning can safely be ignored if you're not doing a parallel build and aren't a kernel maintainer.

That said, if you're submitting code for inclusion in the Linux kernel, please be a good citizen and make sure you identify all of the things your code is dependent upon.  (I'm not actually an active kernel hacker, so I don't know what method they're using for this right now.)

The basic idea is that there are a bunch of steps in compiling things that need to be done in a logical order.  In a small project, we simply use dependencies that we know to put in because we also coded in that dependency.  But with a project the size of the kernel, you can guarantee that not everyone does this.  Some of them instead just specify dependencies if they're needed for things to build properly - if the default order works, things could go years before someone figures out that there was a missing dependency, causing them grief when they were trying to update just the one thing that was a missing dependency, and the other code not getting updated as a result.

When you're doing things in parallel, on the other hand, it becomes a lot more complicated.  Now you really need to have every dependency specified, because there is no longer any inherent dependable order.  Some people will probably still build serially, while others use two processing threads.  I'll use 8.  I've worked in groups that would be inclined to do 30, because they're on a 32 processor machine, and don't really need all of those during the off hours.  Suddenly the fact that the file you needed from a directory that normally got processed 30 directories before yours is now getting processed at the same time as your file that needed it, because you didn't list the dependency and everything in those 30 directories that hasn't already been processed and isn't being processed has a dependency that's not yet finished its processing.